# getText does not return the value, but returns Object Object when I setValue

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

So I have the following problem at hand;

I want to getText from a registrationNumber. so I defined a var regNumber = null;

I defined the var in global.js because I want to access the var throughout the whole test with different pageObjects and outside of a specific function.

When it gets the text and it needs to fill in the text with setValue in the Template Search it returns Object Object, so I tried to use toString but is the same. 
this is the function which I need to use in order to use the var

**module.exports = {**

```
 var regNumber =  browser.globals;
```

**Page Object**

```
        openSearch: function(browser, regNumber ) {
        browser.perform(function () {
        browser.waitForElementVisible('.registrationnumber-search input', 3000)
        browser.setValue('.registrationnumber-search input', regNumber )

            return this;
        })
```

**Test**

```
.continueButton()
browser.getText('xpath', '//*[@id="wizardDetailsTab"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4/span[2]', function (result) {
                        regNumber = result.value
                        console.log(result.value)
                    })

 certificateEditor
        .quickMenu("Permit")
        .createNewItem("template")

    permit
        .openSearch(browser, regNumber)
```

The console.log(result.value) returns the value which I want, however it does not work when I want to use that value in setValue. If I create a function and do the getText in that scope, it fills in what I need. BUt I want to know why it does not work when I try it like this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in your page object :

```
 openSearch: function(regNumber ) {
      return this.perform(function (done) {
        this.api.waitForElementVisible('.registrationnumber-search input', 3000)
        .setValue('.registrationnumber-search input', regNumber )
         done(); //prevent timeout issue
        })
```

Move the code after getText() into it.

```
var permit=client.page.permit() // replace .permit() as .yourpageobjectjsname() 
.....
.continueButton()
browser.getText('xpath', '//*[@id="wizardDetailsTab"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/h4/span[2]', function (result) {
                        regNumber = result.value
                        console.log(result.value)
                        certificateEditor
                                         .quickMenu("Permit")
                                         .createNewItem("template")

                         permit
                                         .openSearch(regNumber)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply was helpful! 
Cheers,
Rody

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it what's happening is you're returning an Object, when you're looking for a string.  I think you just need to designate the object you want.

```
browser.globals
```

should be something like 
    browser.globals.value or browser.globals.text

Your browser.globals is the object being returned.  You have to specify what key/value pair you want that object to return.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! 

Object Object is gone, however it returns now undefined for both value and/or text which you mentioned.